# Converting string taken from URL into list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to take the string I'm receiving from a website using 'getHTML' and turn it into a list of all of the words in the string, but my code doesn't seem to be cooperating. What am I doing wrong?

```
from hmc_urllib import getHTML

def TextClouds():
    url = input('HTML, please:')
    x = getHTML(url)
    return x.split()
```

Comment: Before the line return x.split(), can you print x for an example of x like a google search html so I can see the format of the string you're trying to split?

Comment: You know that `x` will be a tuple, right?

Comment: Nope I did not know that, ive never used getHTML, I dont have python version 3, i assumed its a string haha.

Comment: http://cs.northwestern.edu/~akuzma/classes/EECS110-s09/projects/project2/hmc_urllib.py

Comment: @RHCP41 did you check the answer below?